# Why does query work in PGAdmin but not in Python code?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I created a SQL query and tested it in PGAdmin.  The initial query returned unintended results. The refined query using `()` in the `WHERE` section returned what I expected.
In my Python script the refined query returns an empty list.

I need to iterate over a list of nodes and run the query.
How are the `()` effecting my query `()` causing the empty list?

I've tried different ways of grouping the `WHERE` section and always get an empty list.  Removing the `()` completely every record.

PGADMIN QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name CNA_Name, a.value CNA_Value
FROM nms_node n
LEFT OUTER JOIN nms_node_cna a
ON a.parent = n.id
WHERE   n.long_name  = '006-smtp-in-2l.ems365.company.com' and (a.name = 
'ENV' or a.name = 'Branch' or a.name = 'BRANCH' or a.name = 'ENV' or 
a.name = 'Program' or a.name = 'Support' or a.name = 'Tier' or a.name = 
'tier');
```

RETURNS:

```
long_name   cna_name    cna_value
006-smtp-in-2l.ems365.company.com   Program TBD
006-smtp-in-2l.ems365.company.com   ENV Production
006-smtp-in-2l.ems365.company.com   BRANCH  Network_Services
```

PYTHON CODE

```
OneLineQuery = """
SELECT DISTINCT  a.name CNA_Name , a.value CNA_Value 
FROM nms_node n 
LEFT OUTER JOIN nms_node_cna a 
ON a.parent = n.id 
WHERE  n.long_name  = '%s' and a.name in ('ENV', 'Branch', 'BRANCH', 
'ENV', 'Program', 'Support', 'Tier', 'tier')
""" %(''.join(i))


for i in JUST_NODES_LIST:
    cursor.execute(OneLineQuery.format(i))
    ii = cursor.fetchall()
    print (i,"\t",ii)


['006-smtp-in-2g.ems365.company.com']    []
['006-smtp-in-2i.ems365.company.com']    []
['006-smtp-in-2j.ems365.company.com']    []
['006-smtp-in-2k.ems365.company.com']    []
['006-smtp-in-2l.ems365.company.com']    []
['10.104.1.194']     []
['10.104.120.1']     []
['10.104.152.11']    []
['10.104.2.129']     []
['10.104.2.130']     []
['10.104.217.100']   []
['10.104.232.2']     []
['10.104.240.2']     []
```

I expect to get a list that contains a node and it associated custom attributes like this. `(Node, Attribute Name, Attribute Value)`

```
JRFDTWPNFP001.csa.company.com,BRANCH,Data_Center_Services
JRFDTWPNFP001.csa.company.com,ENV,Production
JRFDTWPNFP001.csa.company.com,Program,TBD
```

Which I would then combine to a single record like `"JRFDTWPNFP001.csa.company.com,BRANCH,Data_Center_Services,ENV,Production,Program,TBD"`

Comment: Your queries are not the same. In sql you have `and (a.name = 'ENV' or a.name = 'Branch' or a.name = 'BRANCH' or a.name = 'ENV' or a.name = 'Program' or a.name = 'Support' or a.name = 'Tier' or a.name = 'tier');`, but in Python you have `and a.name in ('ENV', 'Branch', 'BRANCH', 
'ENV', 'Program', 'Support', 'Tier', 'tier')`. In addition, are you sure %s is not empty? I don't know what is `%(''.join(i))`

Comment: You need to revise your question and re-post the queries and results. As pointed outt he queries are different although your "or ..." list should return the same as the "in list", However  pgadmin query posted did not produce the calmed results. The query selects 2 columns, the claimed results contains 3, not going to happen. The Postgres version the query selects the same 2 columns, but you expect 3 in the result, again not going  to happen, and there is the issue of the '%s' variable value. I guess this is a copy/paste issue but you need to post same query and results consistent with it.